MPAndroidChart Highlight selected Stack bar
I am trying to implement selection in stackedbar of MPAndroidChart library.
the stackbar looks like image 1 when no selection is done

When an stackbar is selected the remaining stackbar is dimmed a little. like in image 2.

How can we achieve it
I have tried using
barDataSet.highLightAlpha = 100
barDataSet.highLightColor = Color.BLUE
barChart.isHighlightFullBarEnabled = true

